# When PreparedStatement.execute() finished, it does not mean that my sql server procedure is over?

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement

I have a Java application where I am executing some queries to a SQL server 2008 database. 
I am trying to execute a stored procedure with that piece of code:

```
//...
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement("exec dbo.myProc");
    preparedStmt.execute();
    connection.commit();
    connection.close();
}
//...
```

But with some debugging I found out that the procedure was not over when the connection is being commited and closed.

So my question is, why is that ? And how can I ensure that the procedure is over before closing the connection ?

Comment: Make sure you have [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798174/sql-server-odbc-driver-not-raising-errors) in the proc code and/or consume all results returned using `preparedStmt.getMoreResults()`.

Comment: using `SET NOCOUNT ON;` worked. But sorry I still do not understand fully. If I call execute() and my proc has multiple operations, it might be locked until I call PrepareStatement#getMoreResults() ?

Comment: I elaborated on my comment with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the proc code and/or consume all results returned using preparedStmt.getMoreResults(). This will ensure the proc runs to completion.

`SET NOCOUNT ON` will suppress `DONE_IN_PROC` (row counts) that need to be consumed. Besides row counts, other operations that return results to the client, such as `SELECT`, `PRINT`, and `RAISERROR`, will require `getMoreResults()` to retrieve the results and ensure the proc runs to completion. If you don't have those in the proc code and no exceptions are raised, `SET NOCOUNT ON` alone will be enough.