# SQL Server Use Encryption for Data results in SECDoClientHandshake error

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

### Short Version

- **ConnectionString**: `Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hydrogen;`
   `User ID=lgilmore;Password=squeegebeckenheim;`
   `Use Encryption for Data=true;`
   `Trust Server Certificate=true;`

gives error:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error

### Background

I am attempting to encrypt communication between SQL Server and an OLEDB client (e.g. ADO, SQLOLEDB).

We note from Microsoft that (unless you've otherwise provisioned one yourself), SQL Server automatically generates a self-signed certificate that is used to secure the login process:

> ### [Using Encryption Without Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-encryption-without-validation)
>
> SQL Server always encrypts network packets associated with logging in. If no certificate has been provisioned on the server when it starts up, SQL Server generates a self-signed certificate which is used to encrypt login packets.

### We can also opt-in to encryption all the time

Our client can request that we use encryption all the time - not just for the login process. Again, from Microsoft:

> Applications may also request encryption of all network traffic by using connection string keywords or connection properties. The keywords are:
>
> - `"Encrypt"`: for ODBC and OLE DB when using a provider string with **IDbInitialize::Initialize**, or
> - `"Use Encryption for Data"` for ADO and OLE DB when using an initialization string with **IDataInitialize**.

This **`Use Encryption for Data`** connection string keyword means we want to use:

- use encryption not just for the login process
- but use encryption also for data

### And we use "Trust Server Certificate" to trust the self-signed cert

The self-signed certificate that SQL Server automatically generates is self-signed. Normally the client driver walks the chain of trust of a certificate in order to see if the certificate is valid. With the automatic self-signed certificate the connection will fail.

But there's a another keyword to force the client to accept the server certificate: **Trust Server Certificate**:

> To enable encryption to be used when a certificate has not been provisioned on the server, applications may use the `"TrustServerCertificate"` keyword or its associated connection attribute to guarantee that encryption takes place. To guarantee encryption even when a server certificate has not been provisioned, an application may request encryption and `"TrustServerCertificate"`.
>
> When `Trust Server Certificate` is set to true, the transport layer will use SSL to encrypt the channel and bypass walking the certificate chain to validate trust.

So we have two keywords:

- **`Use Encryption for Data=true`**: *to opt-in to encryption*
- **`Trust Server Certificate=true`**: *to trust the self-signed certificate*

### Functional Code Example

Now for some minimally reproducible code.

- I'm using OLEDB (e.g. ADO).
- I'm **not** using ADO.NET.
- I'm **not** using ODBC.
- I'm **not** using `SqlClient` (i.e. i'm not using ADO.NET)
- I'm using SQLOLEDB (i.e. Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server).
- I'm **not** using SQL Server Native Client (e.g. SQLNCLI, SQLNCLI11)

And to further drive home i'm using OLEDB, i'll give a code example that uses OLEDB directly (although it is all true for ADO; which is simply a thin wrapper around OLDB):

```
String connectionString = 
      "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hydrogen;"+
      "User ID=lgilmore;Password=squeegebeckenheim;";

//DAInitialize helper class parses the connection string 
IDataInitialize dataInit = (IDataInitialize)CreateComObject(CLSID_MSDAInitialize);

//Ask DAInitialize to create the SQLOLEDB class for us and set it up 
IDBInitialize dataSource;
dataInit.GetDataSource(null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, connectionString, IDBInitialize, ref (IUnknown)dataSource);

//Connect to SQL Server
dataSource.Initialize(); //actually opens the database connection
```

Our initial code sample doesn't request encryption yet; so it's no surprise that we are able to connect. The connection to SQL Server is established without incident. (We can confirm the connection using SQL Profiler).

### Code Example - Encryption Enabled

We refactor the code into a function that accepts a connection string:

```
String connectionString = 
      "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hydrogen;"+
      "User ID=lgilmore;Password=squeegebeckenheim;"+
      "Use Encryption for Data=true"; //opt-in to encryption of data

IDbInitialize dataSource = ConnectToDataSource(connectionString);
```

With our new helper function:

```
IDbInitialize ConnectToDataSource(String connectionString)
{
   //DAInitialize helper class parses the connection string 
   IDataInitialize dataInit = (IDataInitialize)CreateComObject(CLSID_MSDAInitialize);

   //Ask DAInitialize to create the SQLOLEDB class for us and set it up 
   IDBInitialize dataSource;
   dataInit.GetDataSource(null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, connectionString, IDBInitialize, ref (IUnknown)dataSource);

   //Connect to SQL Server
   dataSource.Initialize(); //actually opens the database connection
}
```

We expect this code to fail when connecting to the database. And it does:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error

### Trust server certificate also fails

We now update our connection string to `Trust Server Certificate=true`:

```
String connectionString = 
      "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hydrogen;"+
      "User ID=lgilmore;Password=squeegebeckenheim;"+
      "Use Encryption for Data=true;"+ //opt-into encryption of data
      "Trust Server Certificate=true"; //trust the self-signed server cert
```

but it ***still*** fails with the same error:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error

### SQLOLEDB doesn't recognize Trust Server Certificate

There is a lot of confusion how to specify **`Trust Server Certificate`**. Between initializing an OLEDB provider directly, to using an `IDataInitialize`, to the SQL Server *Native Client* (SQLNCLI), to ADO.net **SqlClient**, and Java ODBC, there are variantions out there:

- `Trust Server Certificate=true`
- `Trust Server Certificate=yes`
- `TrustServerCertificate=true`
- `TrustServerCertificate=yes`

I tried all four of the above variantions; and none worked.

### Ask the provider if it recognizes it

I used the `DataLinks` class have it canonicalize my connection string:

```
String CanonicalizeConnectionString(String cs)
{
   IDataInitialize dataInit = (IDataInitialize)CreateComObject(CLSID_DataLinks);

   IDBInitialize datasource;
   dataInit.GetDataSource(nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, connectionString, IDBInitialize, ref (IUnknown)dataSource);

   String result;
   dataInit.GetInitializationString(dataSource, true, out result);
   return result;
}
```

This gives me my original and the *parsed* connection strings:

- **Original:** `Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hydrogen;User ID=lgilmore;Password=squeegebeckenheim;Use Encryption for Data=true;Trust Server Certificate=true;`
- **Canonicalized:** `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=squeegebeckenheim;User ID=lgilmore;Data Source=hydrogen;Extended Properties="Trust Server Certificate=true";Use Encryption for Data=True`

Given that `Trust Server Certificate` has been put inside the catch-all for unrecognized properties:

- `Extended Properties="Trust Server Certificate=true"`

The fact that it's not recognized means i might have to keep searching for the correct magical syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

Asking a Data Source for all the properties it supports:

```
String EnumerateAllProperties(String connectionString)
{
   IDataInitialize dataInit = (IDataInitialize)CreateComObject(CLSID_MSDAInitialize);

   IDBInitialize dataSource;
   dataInit.GetDataSource(null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, connectionString, IDBInitialize, ref (IUnknown)dataSource);

   String s = "";
   Int32 nSets;
   PDBPropInfoSet pi;
   POleStr desc;
   (dataSource as IDBProperties).GetPropertyInfo(0, null, ref nSets, out pi, ref desc);
   for (int i=0, i <nSets, i++)
   {
      s = s+CRLF+
            PropSetGuidToStr(pi.guidPropertySet);
      for (int j=0, j < pi[i].cPropertyInfos, j++)
      {
         s = s+CRLF+
             IntToStr(pi[i].rgPropertyInfos[j].dwPropertyID)+TAB+
             PWideChar(pi[i].rgPropertyInfos[j].pwszDescription)+TAB+
             VTypeToStr(pi[i].rgPropertyInfos[j].vtType);
      }

      s = s+CRLF;
   }

   return s;
}
```

I realized that SQLOLEDB (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server) doesn't support `Trust Server Certificate`:

**SQLOLEDB - `DBPROPSET_DBINIT` Property Set**

| PropertyID | Description | Type | SQLOLEDB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Integrated Security | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 9 | Password | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 11 | Persist Security Info | VT_BOOL | Yes |
| 12 | User ID | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 59 | Data Source | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 60 | Window Handle | VT_I4 | Yes |
| 64 | Prompt | VT_I2 | Yes |
| 66 | Connect Timeout | VT_I4 | Yes |
| 160 | Extended Properties | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 186 | Locale Identifier | VT_I4 | Yes |
| 233 | Initial Catalog | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 248 | OLE DB Services | VT_I4 | Yes |
| 284 | General Timeout | VT_I4 | Yes |

**SQLOLEDB - `DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDBINIT` property set**

| PropertyID | Description | Type | SQLOLEDB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Current Language | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 5 | Network Address | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 6 | Network Library | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 7 | Use Procedure for Prepare | VT_I4 | Yes |
| 8 | Auto Translate | VT_BOOL | Yes |
| 9 | Packet Size | VT_I4 | Yes |
| 10 | Application Name | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 11 | Workstation ID | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 12 | Initial File Name | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 13 | Use Encryption for Data | VT_BOOL | Yes |
| 14 | Replication server name connect option | VT_BSTR | Yes |
| 15 | Tag with column collation when possible | VT_BOOL | Yes |

Where if you compare that to **SQL Server Native Client 11.0**

**SQL Server Native Client 11.0**

**SQLNCLI11 - `DBPROPSET_DBINIT` Property Set**

| PropertyID | Description | Type | SQLOLEDB | SQLNCLI11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Integrated Security | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 9 | Password | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 11 | Persist Security Info | VT_BOOL | Yes | Yes |
| 12 | User ID | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 59 | Data Source | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 60 | Window Handle | VT_I4 | Yes | Yes |
| 64 | Prompt | VT_I2 | Yes | Yes |
| 66 | Connect Timeout | VT_I4 | Yes | Yes |
| 160 | Extended Properties | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 186 | Locale Identifier | VT_I4 | Yes | Yes |
| 200 | Asynchronous Processing | VT_I4 | No | Yes |
| 233 | Initial Catalog | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 248 | OLE DB Services | VT_I4 | Yes | Yes |
| 284 | General Timeout | VT_I4 | Yes | Yes |

**SQLNCLI11 - `DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDBINIT` property set**

| PropertyID | Description | Type | SQLOLEDB | SQLNCLI11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Current Language | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 5 | Network Address | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 6 | Network Library | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 7 | Use Procedure for Prepare | VT_I4 | Yes | Yes |
| 8 | Auto Translate | VT_BOOL | Yes | Yes |
| 9 | Packet Size | VT_I4 | Yes | Yes |
| 10 | Application Name | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 11 | Workstation ID | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 12 | Initial File Name | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 13 | Use Encryption for Data | VT_BOOL | Yes | Yes |
| 14 | Replication server name connect option | VT_BSTR | Yes | Yes |
| 15 | Tag with column collation when possible | VT_BOOL | Yes | Yes |
| 16 | MARS Connection | VT_BOOL | No | Yes |
| 18 | Failover Partner | VT_BSTR | No | Yes |
| 19 | Old Password | VT_BSTR | No | Yes |
| 20 | DataTypeCompatibility | VT_UI2 | No | Yes |
| **21** | **Trust Server Certificate** | **VT_BOOL** | **No** | **Yes** |
| 22 | Server SPN | VT_BSTR | No | Yes |
| 23 | Failover Partner SPN | VT_BSTR | No | Yes |
| 24 | Application Intent | VT_BSTR | No | Yes |

You can see that the [deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access/) native client supports `Trust Server Certificate`, while the [supported](http://archive.is/JKwDP) OLE DB client does not:

```
| 21         | Trust Server Certificate                | VT_BOOL |   No      | Yes       |
```

This is unfortunate, given the ***"won't fix"*** bugs in the ODBC driver ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511013/reading-columns-out-of-order-returns-incorrect-values-sql-server-odbc-driver), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798174/sql-server-odbc-driver-not-raising-errors), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296182/cannot-execute-synonym-stored-procedure-with-sql-server-odbc-driver-works-with))