# ADODB, SQLSERVER, SERVERPROPERTY: different types using sqloledb or ODBC driver?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, odbc, adodb, sqloledb

I'm trying to switch one of my VBS scripts from using SQLOLEDB to ODBC driver. So long all works like expected - all but one thing:

When fetching *SERVERPROPERTY("is_clustered")* from an MSSQL instance the resulting value is different using each driver.

Here's the output of an example script (script follows below):

> ```
> C:\> cscript test.vbs
>
> Provider: sqloledb
>
> is_clustered (name): is_clustered
> is_clustered (type): 12
> is_clustered (value): 0
>
> Driver: (SQL Server)
>
> is_clustered (name): is_clustered
> is_clustered (type): 204
> C:\test.vbs(33, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch
> ```

Does anyone know what  I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing in my code?

Oh, yes, the code... here's the example script itself:

```
Option Explicit

Dim RS, CONN1, CONN2

Set RS        = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set CONN1      = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
CONN1.ConnectionTimeout = 2
CONN1.Provider = "sqloledb"
CONN1.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"
CONN1.Properties("Data Source").Value = "HOSTNAME\INST01"
CONN1.Open

WScript.echo "Provider: sqloledb" & vbLf
RS.Open "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS is_clustered", CONN1
WScript.echo "is_clustered (name): " & RS.fields(0).Name
WScript.echo "is_clustered (type): " & RS.fields(0).Type
WScript.echo "is_clustered (value): " & RS("is_clustered") & vbLf
RS.Close

Set CONN2      = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
CONN2.ConnectionTimeout = 2
CONN2.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
                         "server=HOSTNAME\INST01;" & _
                         "Trusted_Connection=yes"
CONN2.Open

WScript.echo "Driver: (SQL Server)" & vbLf

RS.Open "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS is_clustered", CONN2
WScript.echo "is_clustered (name): " & RS.fields(0).Name
WScript.echo "is_clustered (type): " & RS.fields(0).Type
WScript.echo "is_clustered (value): " & RS("is_clustered")
RS.Close
```

Many Thanks in advance!

BR,
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

| Driver | SQL Server type | OLEDB type | ADO type | Variant type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SQLOLEDB | sql_variant | `DBTYPE_VARIANT` (12) | `adVariant` (12) | `VT_VARIANT` (12) |
| ODBC | varbinary | `DBTYPE_BYTES` (204) | `adVarBinary` (204) | *n/a* |

So it looks like the legacy SQLOLEDB is getting the value returned to it as type **sql_variant**, but when using the legacy ODBC driver it is coming back as `varbinary`.

This sort of thing isn't unheard of. SQL Server 2005 added `varchar(max)`, `varbinary(max)`, `xml`, and a few others. ADOdb doesn't understand those types, so you would have to be sure to [add an option to your **ConnectionString**:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-ado-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
Server=hyperion; User ID=ruddiger;Password=hunter2;DataTypeCompatibility=80
```

This would cause SQL Server for example to return an `xml` column as **ntext**

- OLEDB type: `DBTYPE_WSTR` (203)
- ADO type: `adLongVarWChar` (203)

Because although they created a new OLEDB type for xml:

- OLEDB type: `DBTYPE_XML` (141)

ADO was never updated after Windows 2000 to know what `DBTYPE` of 141 is. So it would throw an error.

There might be something similar happening here with the legacy SQL Server ODBC driver, and there might be an option that needs to be enabled to cause SQL Server to return *legacy-compatible* data types.

You could also try using the modern, supported, ODBC driver.

> [Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

which has a different name from the legacy:

> SQL Server

But, i would also recommend **not** trying to use any ODBC driver. They have a number of *won't-fix bugs*:

1. Reading columns out of order returns incorrect values

   - reading column values in non-select order gives garbage values:
   - [Reading columns out of order returns incorrect values (SQL Server ODBC driver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511013/reading-columns-out-of-order-returns-incorrect-values-sql-server-odbc-driver)

   It's an ***optional*** performance optimization - that nobody needs or wants. ODBC drivers are perfectly free to support reading columns in any order; the Microsoft driver just refuses to because nobody wants to touch the code.
2. Errors are not raised; but are instead silently eaten

   - errors are not raised (i.e. silently eaten):
   - [SQL Server ODBC Driver not raising errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798174/sql-server-odbc-driver-not-raising-errors)
3. Calling a stored procedure synonym fails

   Except using ODBC Driver to call a synonym procedure fails with:

   ```
   The request for procedure '%s' failed because '%s' is a synonym object
   SQLState: 37000
   NativeError: 2809
   The cursor was not declared.
   SQLState: 37000
   NativeError: 16945
   ```

   - [Cannot execute synonym stored procedure with SQL Server ODBC Driver; works with OLEDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296182/cannot-exeucte-synonym-stored-procedure-with-sql-server-odbc-driver-works-with)

Do download the latest, supported, and *functional*, [MSOLEDBSQL driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

You will need to be sure to add the `DataTypeCompatibiliy=80` in your ADO connection strings.

Also note this note from Microsoft:

> The previous [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (SQLOLEDB) and [SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15) (SQLNCLI) remains deprecated and it is not recommended to use either for new development work.

Comment: Bug #1 has indeed been fixed in more current versions of the ODBC driver, ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511013/reading-columns-out-of-order-returns-incorrect-values-sql-server-odbc-driver#comment126440380_46573806). Bug #2 is a matter of not starting stored procedures and anonymous code blocks with `SET NOTOUNT ON;`.

Comment: @GordThompson The downside of using `SET NOCOUNT ON` means that the server might not return the number of rows affected. Obviously that's not going to work.

Comment: The problem of anonymous code blocks failing silently is that the error is "stuck behind" the rowcount. If we really want to receive the rowcount(s) then we need to check for subsequent results (e.g., by using `.nextset()` with pyodbc in Python) to ensure that we are seeing *all* of them, including any errors that may have occurred.

Comment: In our case we're using OLEDB wrapper around ODBC. So, the correct solution is to use the SQL Server OLEDB driver, and **not** use the SQL Server ODBC driver - because the ODBC driver is full of *wontfix* bugs.